# Browser receives 502 Bad Gateway from the requests to node.js server on IBM Bluemix after the server has run for two days

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

We have seen this problem after the server has run for two days. The problem is disappeared immediately after we restart the server. However, it reoccurs in two days eventually.

The error message is as follows: 
502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.

We have three services on the node.js server. We have seen the problem on the requests to two of these services: one calls the sign-in-with-twitter API, and another calls the APIs of CloudantDB for storing the data received from a request.

Any suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Comment: What problems have you seen on the requests to the sign-in-with-twitter api and CloudantDB api? And do you see the 502 error instanstly when accessing your app or after a certain time (say 120 seconds)?

Comment: If you're getting a 502 error displayed in the browser, there may be something failing within your application code triggering the fronting proxy to return the 502.  When the 502 first occurs, what log messages do you see (cf logs {app name} --recent)?  Try to narrow down what might be triggering app failures by inspecting the logs.

Comment: @whitfiea, the error occurs after a certain time (much close to 2 minutes). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jimmc I will try to collect the console log when I see the problem next time.

Comment: That may simply mean that the node.js app fails to process incoming request any more. One way to debug this problem is to use the App Management feature in Bluemix: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/app_management.html